# udeploy - environment settings

Tags: udeploy

I am learning uDeploy and try to deploy test release (by referring simple HelloWorld application)

1. Created component, component process & application as download artifacts to c:\UAT_1_Rel (Say Environmwnt-1)
   (Source configuration type as file system).

   Provided the sample data as T1.txt and T2.txt and successfully deployed (i.e. in Environmwnt-1)
2. Now Need to deploy this two files into c:\UAT_2_Rel (i.e. in Environmwnt-2)

   For this need to create another component or is any other way (i.e. Want to know how to deploy using single components to Multiple environment)

   Please help to move next step. Your help is highly appreciated.

Note:

The settings already done as given below

Name : CompUAT1
   Source Configuration Type : file system
   Base Path : c:\SrcArt_1_Rel
   Destination Directories : c:\UAT_1_Rel

Resource : TestReso
   Agent    : PTest1

Environment : EnvUAT-1

and done the required settings by Add Base Resources

In the application process design as Install component and added component (CompUAT1)

Answer (score 0):

Using single component you can deploy to multiple environments, its depends on how you have mapped your component in Resource tree.

Create separate group in resource tree for each environment and add your component there.